# String query validate on json data

Tags: java, json

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>()        
data.put("Description","laks");
data.put("EntityName","Pub");
data.put("Severity","Critical");

String query = "Severity = Critical AND (EntityName contains P OR 
EntityName contains p )";
```

In the above sample code I want to apply/validate the "query" string on sample json object "data". Is there any sample code which can help me. In above sample data and query it should return false?

Comment: You should tell us which JSON framework you are using in Java, as this would determine any code which someone might give you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need this library:
https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath